# Why does Tkinter not recognize the Attribute?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to give an output based on which of my Radiobuttons is selected, and the program is working as intended while ignoring the console, where I get this Error Message :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\x\Code\ytinfo.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    self.radiomp3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.container, variable = self.var, value = 1, command = lambda:self.dreiodervier())
  File "C:\Users\x\Code\ytinfo.py", line 32, in dreiodervier
    self.text.insert("end", "\ntop")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2354, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How is that so?
Source Code below and thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):  
        
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        
        self.radiomp3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.container, variable = self.var, value = 1, command = lambda:self.dreiodervier())
        self.radiomp3.pack()
        self.radiomp3.invoke()
        
        self.mp4 = tk.Radiobutton(self.container, variable = self.var, value = 2, command = lambda:self.dreiodervier())
        self.mp4.pack()
        
        self.text = tk.Text(self.container, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=40)
        self.text.pack()
        
        
    def dreiodervier(self):
        
        choice = self.var.get()
        if choice == 1:
            self.text.insert("end", "\ntop")            
           
        else:
            self.text.insert("end", "\nbottom")     


app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: because you inherited tkinter in the class...

Comment: `self.radiomp3.invoke()` is resulting in an immediate call to `dreiodervier()` - but that method makes use of `self.text`, which won't be defined until about 5 lines later.  Move the `.invoke()` down to the bottom of the function.